# Can we limit number of sessions can be obtained from SessionFactory?

Tags: hibernate, session, sessionfactory

Can we limit sessions obtained from  SessionFactory ? Is it internally linked with number of connections database can handle ?

If yes, which property of  SessionFactory  is used to set the limit value ?

And what will happen if number of connections my database can handle is less than number of sessions created ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your question depends totally on individuals' requirement, if one wishes to limit the sessions granted by the `Session-Factory` can be perfectly implemented by creating your own utility class in which you can define your own business logic for number of `Sessions` granted by the `SessionFactory`. I have below code which shows the way to achieve the result in very general form.

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class FactoryUtil  {

public static SessionFactory factory=null;  //Here I have Initialized the object of SessionFactory to null.
public static final int MAX_SESS = 10;  //Here user can declare value of MAX_SESS to the number of session objects to be granted by the SessionFactory.
public static int counter = 0;  //Similarly, user can take counter to execute the logic till the limit is specified above.

 /*declaring below method as private static so that it 
   should only be accessible through the name of the class and not by any 
   other object outside the class also it will have common logic to all 
   the objects of the class. It will return the object of type 
   SessionFactory which will now hold the config required for 
   communication from your java application related to specific database. 
 */

private static SessionFactory getFactory() {

    System.out.println("Receiving new call to create new SF object.");

    if(factory==null){

       System.out.println("New SeSFaC created.");

        factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.mysqlcfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

    }

    return factory;
}

/*Specify the logic as per your requirement. Here I'm jst validating 
  the number of session objects to be created by SessionFactory are equal 
  to the MAX_SESS the user wants to be generated. Similarly I have tried 
  catch the exception if the number of sessions granted exceeds the limit 
  specified and display the warning msg back to the user. It will return 
  me the session object which is created using the config provided inside 
  the getFactory method.  
*/   

public static Session getSession() throws Exception{

Session ss = null ;

        if(counter <= MAX_SESS){

            ss = FactoryUtil.getFactory().openSession();

            counter++;
        }
        else {

            System.out.println("No.of Session limit exceeded.");
            try{
                throw new Exception("No. of limit exceed"); 
            }
            catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    return ss;
}

}
```

I hope the above clears your doubt for your query.

Comment: Make ```public static int counter = 1; ``` or change the if condition to ```counter < MAX_SESS```. Otherwise it'll execute 11 times if ```MAX_SESS = 10;```.